# How to find all element from str

Tags: python

I want to find all element in dict from str.

I try to write code, but it doesn't work well.

I consider using recursive function.

```
str = "xx111xxx200x222x"
nums = {"one hundreds": ["100","111"], "two hundreds": ["200", "222"]}
result = []

def allfind(data):
    for key in nums.keys():
        for num in nums[key]:
            index = data.find(num)
            if index > -1:
                result.append(key)
                return allfind(data[index+len(num):])


allfind("xx111xxx200x222x")
print result # return ["two hundreds", "two hundreds"]
# I want to get ["one hundreds", "two hundreds", "two hundreds"]
```

Comment: Does the order matter?

Comment: use re `re.split('x+', "xx111xxx200x222x")` then find key for values in dict.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would have transformed the dictionary to have all the values as keys and the key as corresponding values and using the [RegEx suggested by Grijesh Chauhan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22523047/how-to-find-all-element-from-str#comment34272460_22523047), getting the values will be easy like this

```
nums, my_str = {num:key for key in nums for num in nums[key]}, "xx111xxx200x222x"
import re
print nums
# {'200': 'two hundreds', '100': 'one hundreds', '111': 'one hundreds', '222': 'two hundreds'}
print [nums[item] for item in re.split('x+', my_str) if nums.get(item, "")]
# ['one hundreds', 'two hundreds', 'two hundreds']
```

Comment: Ahaa so you first created reversed dict as {value: keys}, so that later indexing becomes O(1) Nice. I will keep this trick in mind. Helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

you can do something like(read comments):

```
>>> import re
>>> r = [] # return list 
>>> for i in re.split('x+', "xx111xxx200x222x"): # outer loop
...  for k in nums: # iterate for each key
...   if i in nums[k]: # check if i in list at key
...    r.append(k) # if true add in return list
... 
>>> r
['one hundreds', 'two hundreds', 'two hundreds']
```

Note in outer loop you are iterating for following:

```
>>> re.split('x+', "xx111xxx200x222x")
['', '111', '200', '222', '']
# ^                       ^  doesn't exists in dict values.
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason because you are getting wrong answer is because nums is a dictionary and is orderless and so,

```
nums.keys() becomes ['two hundreds', 'one hundreds']
```

Hence you have two hundreds as your first result and then when you do

```
return allfind(data[index+len(num):])
```

it returns the string x222x. Which ofcourse has only "two hundreds" (222), so final result becomes

```
['two hundreds', 'two hundreds']
```

The solution, which I think you can do it after knowing the error, should come when you iterate over the nums keys in correct order. (Think list).

Also, try putting simple print statements for easy debugging, whenever possible.

Comment: I always prefer this kind of answer, but he is getting one `'two hundreds'`? ...check this print's comment

Comment: He is getting 2 two hundreds, => print result # return ["two hundreds", "two hundreds"]

Comment: yes but I couldn't understand why he is missing "one hundred" (even after reading your answer.) ok I read again.

Comment: yikes!, that means the explanation wasnt good enough. Edited again. Let me know if I am clear this time.